# NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am developing an Android App. I have the below code to write a list of all files starting with XLR in a particular folder:

```
private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        try {
            if ((file.exists()) && (file != null)) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
                } else {
                    if (file.getName().startsWith("XLR")) {
                        inFiles.add(file);
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return inFiles;
}
```

On Android 10 and 11 it seems to be a problem. For Android 10 I have legacy storage enabled and Android 11 I have got access to all files. So the issue is not file access.
The folder itself might not be in my app's folder, hence the need to be able to list out files

I know that there is an extensive page here on NPE's and I have tried my best to follow the advice there (I am checking that files exist and are not null), but still to no avail.

I feel that there's probably something so stupid, that a more experienced programmer would probably pick out in 2 seconds...

Comment: if (files==null) return null; Or return inFiles;

Comment: switch file.exists and file != null in first IF

Comment: @blackapps would that even make a difference ? the for loop will only iterate over actual instances, meaning that they can't be null, right ? or am i wrong, i haven't done java in a long time

Comment: @Autocrab same question to you :)

Comment: open listFiles method and read if there can be null in result array. Also on which line it fires NPE?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, i understand the difference but even swapped its not the solution. By the way: you are missing in the list of people now to be elected for moderator ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem would be easily solved just reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) of the actual `File` package.

Documentation on the method `File::listFiles`:

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

As you can see, that method can actually return `null` and not only an empty array, so you should check that the value isn't null before even trying to iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks for this - I changed to top few lines to this:private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
  ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
  File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
  if (files != null) {